# Как печатать «Ё» в сочетаниях (CapsLock or Shift) + Alt + t?

Tags: autohotkey

На моей клавиатуре нет клавиши ё (клавиатура 65%), но я её использую. Если со строчной «ё» проблем не возникает, то вот с заглавной проблемы есть.
Для строчной ё я использую такой скрипт:
`<!t:: Send, ё`

Для заглавной я написал скрипт с использованием Shift:
`<!+t:: Send, Ё`

Но я совсем не понимаю, как учитывать здесь нажатие капслока. Я попытался написать вот это:

```
#If, GetKeyState("CapsLock")
<!t::
    Send, Ё 
return
```

Но скрипт всё равно возвращает строчную «ё», не учитывая капслок.

Comment: `Alt` + `0168` на цифровой клавиатуре.

Comment: клавиатура 65%, на ней нет цифрового блока.

Answer (score 0):

`Alt` + `0168` на цифровой клавиатуре.

UPD:

Удалось нагуглить такой вариант:

`Send {ASC 0168}`

Comment: клавиатура 65% — цифрового блока нет, да и вопрос с тегом про аутохоткей.

Comment: @АртурХисматулин, обновил ответ.